create a typing.Literal from a list
I have a list created from the combination of valid letters, say 'A' and 'B' which gives valids = ['AA','AB','BA','BB']. I want to provide these combinations as valid Literal entries. How can I do this? Literal[valids] doesn't work.
I could modify the combination source function as needed it this makes it easier.
A related question does not explain how to get 'valids' into the Literal, though.

"A related question does not explain how to get 'valids' into the Literal": If you read the accepted answer carefully, you will see that you ought to do it the other way around.
